# Character counting program not outputting anything?

Tags: c, linux, unix

Sorry for asking such a simple question, I'm still learning C and going through the basics first.

I'm creating a character counting program and yet when I execute the program and try to input "h" for example and then press enter a new line appears and nothing is outputted onto that line?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Copy input and count characters 2nd version */

main() {
    double cc;
    for(cc = 0; getchar() != EOF; ++cc);
    printf("%.0f\n", cc);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have finished entering characters, you have to signal the end of input stream by pressing `Ctrl-D`. Otherwise your program will continue waiting for more input.

P.S. Why are you using a `double` variable for the counter? An integer type would be more appropriate.

Comment: Isn't it twice the length of a float? I just thought it would be better to use.

Comment: @TheBlueCat: Since `cc` is just a counter, I think the best default choice for its type is `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe (I'm not sure what exactly do you want) you have an extra `;` after the `for()`, which mean an empty statement. So your program will run the empty statement (in other words, do nothing) until the end of input (if the input is terminal, you may need a `CTRL+D`), and then print (once) the number of characters.

If you want your program to print the counter after every char in the input, remove that `;`, so the `printf` will be in the loop.

Comment: According to the book I'm reading it's for a "Null statement"

Comment: Well, I didn't know exactly what do you want. if you wanted to use empty loop (and to print only at the end of the input), aix`s answer are really good.

Answer (score -2):

Include this line at the end you will get output:

```
return 0;
```