# Character counting program doesn't output anything

Tags: c, mingw32

I've tried Dev-C++ and MinGW(32-bit) but every time i run the code, nothing outputs. I'm using windows 7. below is my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
  long nc;
  nc=0;
  while(getchar()!=EOF)
    ++nc;
  printf("Number of chars are %ld ",nc);
}
```

I've also tried [pressing Ctrl-D to signal the EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365973/character-counting-program-not-outputting-anything) but it's not working. when I input " rajkumar " and [enter] it doesn't do anything. when i input " rajkumar " and ^Z [enter] twice, it ends. all i'm asking is why it doesn't print the expected output? and when i tried it first time it worked fine twice, but then i don't know what went wrong.

Comment: Do you press enter after the input ?

Comment: I think on Windows, it is not C-d but C-z or something.

Comment: yes, i did and nothing comes except the blinking cursor

Comment: also tried C-z, but no

Comment: I am in linux and it works...

Comment: If the Windows shell understands this, also try running it on input redirected from a file like `./your-program < some-file`. But we'll have to wait for a Windows guy to come by and tell whether that is okay. Or you'll have to look up the manual of your shell yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EOF reading C/C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406588/eof-reading-c-c)

Comment: Could you specify what **exactly** you input?

Comment: @cool, entered my name, rajkumar

Comment: @ninga , dude i've edited the question. please care to answer it

Comment: Try adding something like `getchar();` just after the `printf`. Or maybe `int c; while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);`

Comment: there are only a couple of valid ways to declare the main() function when running an OS. (like Windows)  `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`  and `int main( void )`   and one optional way: `int main()`.   Notice that they ALL have return type of 'int'

Comment: regarding this line: `printf("Number of chars are %ld ",nc);`  stdout is buffered.  it can be 'flushed' to the terminal in several ways.  The most common is to end the format string with '\n'.   Suggest: `printf("Number of chars are %ld\n ",nc);`

Comment: if you typed `rajkumar` then naturally nothing happened.   The desired sequence is: `rajkumar<cr><Ctrl-Z><cr>`   because nothing is passed to the program until the 'enter' key is pressed. and the program will not exit the loop until it receives a <Ctrl-Z> (<Ctrl-D> for linux) and the <Ctrl-Z> must be the first char on a new line

Answer (score 3):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406588/eof-reading-c-c), to trigger EOF detection,

- **first** do <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
- then press <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> (or ^D on Linux), that has to be at the beginning of the line
- press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> again if detection was still not triggered

Answer (score 1):

To signal EOF on Windows, press Ctrl-Z followed by Enter.

Note: this is for the Windows console. If you're running the program inside your IDE, your IDE may or may not have a way to signal EOF.

Answer (score 0):

`getchar()` gets a single character and it also accepts Enter. So if you press r and then Enter, its only r that gets entered. So you need to press Enter after pressing the keys. Without Enter, getchar() won't accept the character.

Comment: but it doesn't even print r. in fact, it worked very fine the first time i tried